# Pandas Seaborn Swarmplot doesn't plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot a seaborn swarmplot where col[2] is the freq and col[3] are the classes to be grouped by. Input is given below and the code too. 
Input

```
tweetcricscore,51,high active
tweetcricscore,46,event based
tweetcricscore,12,event based
tweetcricscore,46,event based
tweetcricscore,1,viewers 
tweetcricscore,178,viewers
tweetcricscore,46,situational
tweetcricscore,23,situational
tweetcricscore,1,situational
tweetcricscore,8,situational
tweetcricscore,56,situational
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header = None)

df.columns = ['keyword','freq','class']

ax = sns.swarmplot(x="class", y="freq", data=df)

plt.show()
```

The code wouldn't plot nor would give any error. Any suggestion to optimize the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), then create new column class by concanecate with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and last [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) whitespaces:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import io

temp=u"""tweetcricscore 51 high active
tweetcricscore 46 event based
tweetcricscore 12 event based
tweetcricscore 46 event based
tweetcricscore 1 viewers 
tweetcricscore 178 viewers
tweetcricscore 46 situational
tweetcricscore 23 situational
tweetcricscore 1 situational
tweetcricscore 8 situational
tweetcricscore 56 situational"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+", #separator is arbitrary whitespace
                 names=['keyword','freq','class1','class2']) #set new col names
```

```
df['class'] = df['class1'] + ' ' + df['class2'].fillna('')
df['class'] = df['class'].str.strip()
print df
           keyword  freq       class1  class2        class
0   tweetcricscore    51         high  active  high active
1   tweetcricscore    46        event   based  event based
2   tweetcricscore    12        event   based  event based
3   tweetcricscore    46        event   based  event based
4   tweetcricscore     1      viewers     NaN      viewers
5   tweetcricscore   178      viewers     NaN      viewers
6   tweetcricscore    46  situational     NaN  situational
7   tweetcricscore    23  situational     NaN  situational
8   tweetcricscore     1  situational     NaN  situational
9   tweetcricscore     8  situational     NaN  situational
10  tweetcricscore    56  situational     NaN  situational

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="class", y="freq", data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Solution if column `class` not contains whitespaces:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import io

temp=u"""tweetcricscore 51 highactive
tweetcricscore 46 eventbased
tweetcricscore 12 eventbased
tweetcricscore 46 eventbased
tweetcricscore 1 viewers 
tweetcricscore 178 viewers
tweetcricscore 46 situational
tweetcricscore 23 situational
tweetcricscore 1 situational
tweetcricscore 8 situational
tweetcricscore 56 situational"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+", #separator is arbitrary whitespace
                 names=['keyword','freq','class']) #set new col names
print df
```

```
           keyword  freq        class
0   tweetcricscore    51   highactive
1   tweetcricscore    46   eventbased
2   tweetcricscore    12   eventbased
3   tweetcricscore    46   eventbased
4   tweetcricscore     1      viewers
5   tweetcricscore   178      viewers
6   tweetcricscore    46  situational
7   tweetcricscore    23  situational
8   tweetcricscore     1  situational
9   tweetcricscore     8  situational
10  tweetcricscore    56  situational

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="class", y="freq", data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph1]

EDIT2:

If separator is `,` use:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import io

temp=u"""tweetcricscore,51,high active
tweetcricscore,46,event based
tweetcricscore,12,event based
tweetcricscore,46,event based
tweetcricscore,1,viewers
tweetcricscore,178,viewers
tweetcricscore,46,situational
tweetcricscore,23,situational
tweetcricscore,1,situational
tweetcricscore,8,situational
tweetcricscore,56,situational"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=['keyword','freq','class'])
```

```
print df
           keyword  freq        class
0   tweetcricscore    51  high active
1   tweetcricscore    46  event based
2   tweetcricscore    12  event based
3   tweetcricscore    46  event based
4   tweetcricscore     1      viewers
5   tweetcricscore   178      viewers
6   tweetcricscore    46  situational
7   tweetcricscore    23  situational
8   tweetcricscore     1  situational
9   tweetcricscore     8  situational
10  tweetcricscore    56  situational

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="class", y="freq", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My apologies, But, While I was updating the input you posted the answer. Can you please check the input format again.

Comment: My request if you are making changes pls keep this solution as it is someone can refer to it and any new change pls make as update section.

Comment: `Col[3]` has space for words `high active and event based` will be considered as new column when the separator is `,` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And `sep=','` is default separator, so you can use `df = pd.read_csv('filename', names=['keyword','freq','class'])`

Comment: Opps, I didnt notice change of separator. So please check edit2.

Comment: Yes I did ..the code is running the real data which is more than 1000 rows. `print df` is printing the rows once done and I see the plot I shall reply you. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Comment: Definitely .. I am just waiting for the plot to show .. not moving this page anywhere ;)

Comment: No problem. Only I think you forget. ;)

Comment: NO worries I have accepted the ans in case of any set back will write here again. Looks like the process is take way too long time than expected.

Comment: What is size of dataframe? Is large?

Comment: About 8000+ rows the df is loaded in pandas but it wouldn't plot :(

Comment: Hmmm, but then problem can be in seaborn. :(

Comment: I had this doubt before posting the main question if the version was outdated hence I updated the version of seaborn. But I have one a doubt one of the columns has names with `#` in them. Unlike `numpy gentext` does `pandas` ` dataframe` take them as `comments` ?

Comment: Even with change in input file. The one which is exactly like the one in above question yet it is same problem. Now the rows are 3000+ they are loaded in df as print df is showing it on terminal but wont plot :( will it be ok if  I share the real input file on dropbox link ?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Good idea.

Comment: Updated seaborn, matplotlib and pandas just now and still the same problem :(

Comment: I try it and this is too many rows for seaborn. For me it works, but with problems. I try find solution.

Comment: It cannot be too many rows for seaborn as I am already plotting `kde` plots using seaborn and `scatter plot` using bokeh with same data. In case of kde I am putting it in numpy array but grouping isnt easy with numpy, where as in bokeh its very easy to group but bokeh has no swarmplot . Thank you so the support by far I will wait for your help on this.

Comment: Ok, I think it is problem. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35586669/2901002) and in [docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot) - `although it does not scale as well to large numbers of observations`

Comment: Let me check if I can read individual classes as separate input files. May be that might give me some idea.

Comment: I think it is no necessary. You can groupby your data by `classes`, see more info about [groupby](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/) and then try in loop draw it. But for me 200 rows works with problems, so 8k is to many. :( (the easiest filter is `df = df[:200]` or `df = df.head(200)`)

Comment: Sure I will try group by.  But do we have any alternative that can allow similar kind of plots.

Comment: Jezrael: Thank you so much for the support. I found an alternative. Using `groupby` classes and putting the same grouped classes as `x` axis and the values as `y` axis and plot a `bokeh` scatter plot which allows me have `color` and `marker` respect to group. Let me post the solution in case someone like me is struggling with univariate values.

Answer (score 0):

After several trails in plotting `swamplot` with the dataset of more than `8-10k` rows and with constant help and suggestions by [jezreal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael). We come to conclusion that `seaborn` category plotting `swarmplot` cannot scale the large data like the other plots from `seaborn` which is also mentioned in the tutorial document. Hence I change the plotting style to `bokeh` scatter plot where I use the numeric values on `y` axis and grouped category names on `x` axis and this kinda solved my problem of plotting `univariate` data plotting with a category.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models import BoxSelectTool, BoxZoomTool, LassoSelectTool
from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure, hplot, vplot
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header = None)

df.columns = ['user','freq','class']

scatter = Scatter( df, x='class', y='freq', color='class', marker='class', title=' User classification', legend=False)

output_file('output.html', title='output')

show(scatter)
```

This allowing grouping by `class` column with allocating colors and markers according to the groups. The `freq` is plotted along the y axis. [image: output]

**Note: This might have accidentally worked as the data is discrete is nature.**